# Weird memory issue on Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android

My application crashes on the Samsung Galaxy Note, apparently due to memory issues.  The weird part is that my app does not appear to be using a particularly large amount of memory at the time of the crash.  However, according to the logs, the OS seems to think that memory is running low and starts killing all active processes (including my app).  I don't see this behavior on any other device I've tried (test devices include: Acer Iconiatab, Samsung Galaxy Tab, Droid3 phone, Nook color, LG Optimus V).

My suspicion is that this is related to the android build included on the device, maybe it does something funky and wrong in handling low memory situations.  Any ideas about what could cause this sort of behavior, or suggestions about how I can rectify it?

The garbage collections log immediately prior to dying, shows moderate memory usage (I know that these are from my app based on the PID):

```
11-22 13:58:45.200: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1649K, 56% free 5042K/11335K, external 4791K/5982K, paused 1ms+5ms
11-22 13:58:45.770: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2081K, 56% free 5009K/11335K, external 4791K/5982K, paused 2ms+4ms
11-22 13:58:46.705: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1951K, 56% free 5044K/11335K, external 4791K/5982K, paused 2ms+4ms
11-22 13:58:47.690: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31965): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2250K, 58% free 4842K/11335K, external 4791K/5982K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

And this is log the message from the os starts killing everything:

```
11-22 13:58:45.175: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.app.fm (pid 31915) has died.
11-22 13:58:45.225: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2 (pid 32069) has died.
11-22 13:58:45.340: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.android.MtpApplication (pid 32078) has died.
11-22 13:58:45.340: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:45.745: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:45.890: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40916e70 MYAPP (server)'
11-22 13:58:45.890: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'PenGestureView (server)'
11-22 13:58:46.365: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.app.twlauncher (pid 31611) has died.
11-22 13:58:46.365: ERROR/InputDispatcher(2764): channel '409d9788 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-22 13:58:46.365: ERROR/InputDispatcher(2764): channel '409d9788 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-22 13:58:46.365: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:46.370: INFO/WindowManager(2764): WIN DEATH: Window{409d9788 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher paused=false}
11-22 13:58:46.375: DEBUG/InputTransport(2764): Input channel destroyed: name='409d9788 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher (server)', ashmemFd=17, receivePipeFd=158, sendPipeFd=157
11-22 13:58:46.375: INFO/WindowManager(2764): WIN DEATH: Window{40a398d0 SurfaceView paused=false}
11-22 13:58:47.010: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.android.providers.calendar (pid 31765) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.010: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.115: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService (pid 31578) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.120: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService in 5000ms
11-22 13:58:47.120: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.180: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.app.FileTransferServer (pid 31606) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.180: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.app.FileTransferServer/.FTSService in 14940ms
11-22 13:58:47.180: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.180: ERROR/WifiService(2764): Multicaster binderDied
11-22 13:58:47.250: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:47.250: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:47.250: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:47.250: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:47.280: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock (pid 31676) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.280: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock/.DigitalClockService in 24846ms
11-22 13:58:47.280: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.370: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.widgetapp.emailwidget (pid 31698) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.370: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.widgetapp.emailwidget/.EmailUpdateService in 34750ms
11-22 13:58:47.370: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.455: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.sec.android.app.FileTransferManager (pid 31742) has died.
11-22 13:58:47.455: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.app.FileTransferManager/.FTSRunningChecker in 44671ms
11-22 13:58:47.455: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:47.490: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
11-22 13:58:47.490: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40916e70 MYAPP(server)'
11-22 13:58:47.490: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel 'PenGestureView (server)'
11-22 13:58:47.490: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
11-22 13:58:47.490: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 3->7|0
11-22 13:58:47.490: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 32
11-22 13:58:47.775: WARN/WifiStateTracker(2764): ------ msg.what =8
11-22 13:58:47.860: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:48.370: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.samsung.sec.android.inputmethod.axt9 (pid 31652) has died.
11-22 13:58:48.435: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.samsung.sec.android.inputmethod.axt9/.AxT9IME in 53698ms
11-22 13:58:48.445: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:49.510: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:49.890: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:50.135: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:50.160: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:50.240: DEBUG/LocationProviderProxy(2764): LocationProviderProxy.onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
11-22 13:58:50.240: DEBUG/GeocoderProxy(2764): onServiceDisconnected ComponentInfo{com.google.android.location/com.google.android.location.NetworkLocationService}
11-22 13:58:50.595: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 31621) has died.
11-22 13:58:50.785: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService in 61462ms
11-22 13:58:50.790: WARN/ActivityManager(2764): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.location/.NetworkLocationService in 71437ms
11-22 13:58:50.825: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:50.965: WARN/WifiStateTracker(2764): ------ msg.what =8
11-22 13:58:51.085: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:51.100: DEBUG/InputDispatcher(2764): findTouchedWindow finished: injectionResult=-1, injectionPermission=1, timeSpentWaitingForApplication=3226.7ms
11-22 13:58:51.450: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:51.700: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(31965): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
11-22 13:58:51.705: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'PenGestureView (server)'
11-22 13:58:51.925: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 3->7|0
11-22 13:58:51.925: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 32
11-22 13:58:51.980: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
11-22 13:58:52.130: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:52.565: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:52.700: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel 'PenGestureView (server)'
11-22 13:58:52.765: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:52.775: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:52.775: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:52.800: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:52.880: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=2
11-22 13:58:53.345: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService for service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService: pid=32167 uid=10073 gids={3003, 1015}
11-22 13:58:53.360: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:53.635: VERBOSE/ThermistorObserver(2764):  mThermistorState =0, Thermistor temperature: 440
11-22 13:58:53.870: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:54.100: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=2
11-22 13:58:54.270: WARN/WifiStateTracker(2764): ------ msg.what =8
11-22 13:58:54.450: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:54.455: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:54.790: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:55.035: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:55.160: INFO/InputReader(2764): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=1
11-22 13:58:56.655: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'PenGestureView (server)'
11-22 13:58:57.095: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 3->7|0
11-22 13:58:57.100: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 32
11-22 13:58:57.105: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
11-22 13:58:57.290: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:57.290: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:57.290: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:57.555: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:59.685: WARN/WifiStateTracker(2764): ------ msg.what =8
11-22 13:58:59.730: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Process MYAPP (pid 31965) has died.
11-22 13:58:59.775: INFO/WindowManager(2764): WIN DEATH: Window{40916e70 MYAPP paused=false}
11-22 13:58:59.785: ERROR/InputDispatcher(2764): channel '40916e70 MYAPP (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-22 13:58:59.785: ERROR/InputDispatcher(2764): channel '40916e70 MYAPP (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-22 13:58:59.800: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(2764): id=601 Removed MYAPP idx=1 Map Size=4
11-22 13:58:59.805: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
11-22 13:58:59.805: DEBUG/InputDispatcher(2764): findTouchedWindow finished: injectionResult=2, injectionPermission=1, timeSpentWaitingForApplication=3153.9ms
11-22 13:58:59.805: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(2764): remove count:1 destroying MYAPP
11-22 13:58:59.845: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
11-22 13:58:59.845: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 3->7|0
11-22 13:58:59.845: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 32
11-22 13:58:59.850: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
11-22 13:58:59.850: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
11-22 13:58:59.855: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:59.855: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
11-22 13:58:59.855: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
11-22 13:58:59.855: INFO/InputDispatcher(2764): Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
11-22 13:58:59.855: ERROR/lights(2764): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-22 13:58:59.855: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:59.855: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:59.855: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:59.855: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:59.855: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 3->7|0
11-22 13:58:59.855: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 32
11-22 13:58:59.855: WARN/PowerManagerService(2764): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
11-22 13:58:59.855: INFO/PowerManagerService(2764): Ulight 7->3|0
11-22 13:58:59.855: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2764): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
11-22 13:58:59.865: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Start proc com.sec.android.app.twlauncher for activity com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/.Launcher: pid=32174 uid=10015 gids={3003, 1015, 3002}
11-22 13:58:59.865: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Low Memory: No more background processes.
11-22 13:58:59.885: INFO/Zygote(32174): Zygote: pid 32174 has CALL PRIVILEGED permission, then set capability for CAP_SYS_ADMIN (21)
11-22 13:58:59.900: INFO/OrientationDebug(2764): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
11-22 13:58:59.900: VERBOSE/OrientationDebug(2764): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=1, SensorEnabled=true
11-22 13:58:59.900: INFO/OrientationDebug(2764): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return true #4
11-22 13:58:59.900: ERROR/WindowManager(2764): rotation is : 0
11-22 13:58:59.995: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(2764): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1322049600.000000000
11-22 13:58:59.995: VERBOSE/AlarmManager(2764): sending alarm Alarm{4087e470 type 1 android}
11-22 13:59:00.000: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(2764): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1321970400.000000000
11-22 13:59:00.000: VERBOSE/AlarmManager(2764): Adding alarm Alarm{40514880 type 1 android} at 0
11-22 13:59:00.030: INFO/ActivityThread(32174): Pub com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.settings: com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.LauncherProvider
11-22 13:59:00.150: INFO/lcdtest(32174): MODEL : GT-N7000
11-22 13:59:00.150: INFO/lcdtest(32174): Default setting
11-22 13:59:00.150: INFO/lcdtest(32174): Unknown MODEL : GT-N7000
11-22 13:59:00.225: INFO/Launcher(32174): Launcher created: 405373c8
11-22 13:59:00.235: INFO/Launcher(32174): onCreate. Launcher: 405373c8, mDestroyed: false
11-22 13:59:00.245: INFO/Launcher(32174): onCreate():  product model family:Q1 product model : xx-xxxx
11-22 13:59:00.345: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Start proc com.google.process.gapps for content provider com.google.android.gsf/.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider: pid=32182 uid=10061 gids={3003, 1015, 2001, 1007}
11-22 13:59:00.385: DEBUG/Launcher(32174): It's image wallpaper. suggestDesiredDimensions(-1,-1)
11-22 13:59:00.465: INFO/ActivityThread(32182): Pub com.google.settings: com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider
11-22 13:59:00.505: INFO/ActivityThread(32182): Pub subscribedfeeds: com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.SubscribedFeedsProvider
11-22 13:59:00.595: INFO/ActivityThread(32182): Pub com.google.android.gsf.gservices: com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider
11-22 13:59:00.600: INFO/GservicesProvider(32182): Gservices pushing to system: true; secure: true
11-22 13:59:00.600: INFO/ActivityThread(32182): Pub com.google.android.providers.talk: com.google.android.gsf.talk.TalkProvider
11-22 13:59:00.665: DEBUG/NlpVersionInfo(32167): com.google.android.location not found
11-22 13:59:00.685: DEBUG/SyncManager(2764): setSyncAutomatically: , provider subscribedfeeds -> true
11-22 13:59:00.685: DEBUG/SyncManager(2764): setSyncAutomatically: already set to true, doing nothing
11-22 13:59:01.280: DEBUG/GLSurfaceViewGroup(32174): setting 8888 buffer for live wallpaper
11-22 13:59:01.290: ERROR/(32174): About to try to load SceneGraph
11-22 13:59:01.290: ERROR/(32174): SceneGraph_nativeClassInit
11-22 13:59:01.295: INFO/GLThread(32174): starting tid=10
11-22 13:59:01.295: INFO/GLThread(32174): noticed surfaceView surface lost tid=10
11-22 13:59:01.305: INFO/DebugFolder(32174): Setting folder model to com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.UserFolderModel@4053fb70 in mode 0
11-22 13:59:01.305: INFO/DebugFolder(32174): Set Folder Model Dumping Added
11-22 13:59:01.305: INFO/DebugFolder(32174): Set Folder Model Dumping Deleted
11-22 13:59:01.305: INFO/DebugFolder(32174): Set Folder Model Dumping Current
11-22 13:59:01.305: INFO/DebugFolder(32174): Set Folder Model Dumping Special
11-22 13:59:01.315: DEBUG/Launcher(32174): startLoaders. Launcher: 405373c8
11-22 13:59:01.330: INFO/Database(32174): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 6 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/launcher.db-wal
11-22 13:59:01.340: DEBUG/Launcher.LauncherModel(32174): dropTopApplicationCache
11-22 13:59:01.400: INFO/ActivityManager(2764): Start proc com.sec.android.provider.badge for content provider com.sec.android.provider.badge/.BadgeProvider: pid=32193 uid=10105 gids={}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into developer options under settings. You probably have something checked on like:

Do not keep activities

or

Limit background processes is set very low.

I used to test on a Note 1 (I have a Note 2) and one of these settings really messed me up for a long time. It is good to get your code running with them enabled as it is a worst case scenario but not something that really happens out in the wild.